# Is there a way to define a UDTF in snowflake without having to write out all the columns?

Tags: sql, function, return, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am creating a function similar to this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION("_ID" VARCHAR(16777216))
RETURNS TABLE
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
' SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE IDENTIFICATION = _ID
';
```

MY_TABLE contains about 400 columns and I want the function to return a table of all of them. Is there a way I can do this without having to write out all the columns and their types in

`RETURNS TABLE (COLUMN_1 NUMBER(38,0), COLUMN_2 VARCHAR(16777216), .....)` etc?

I tried

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION("_ID" VARCHAR(16777216))
RETURNS TABLE ()
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
' SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE IDENTIFICATION = _ID
';
```

But it gives back an error saying `Mismatch between declared return signature column count (0) and actual column count (431)` and it would be really inconvenient to have to list out 431 columns and their types.

Comment: As far as I can see you need to add at least one column for the RETURNS TABLE, so it's not possible to return directly all columns without adding them.

Comment: Ah ok, that is unfortunate, thank you!

Comment: I have created an idea: https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas called: `Expand asterisk (SELECT *) to column list for an arbitrary query` - it would be nice to have expansion of `*` built-in UI

Answer (score 0):

To make life a bit easier the column definition for `TABLE()` could be generated:

```
-- main query here
SELECT *
FROM TAB;

DESCRIBE RESULT LAST_QUERY_ID();

SELECT LISTAGG(CONCAT("name", ' ', "type"), ',\n') AS column_types
FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Procedure instead of Table function , Procedure allows return of resultset as Table without declaring data types of columns in Procedure return clause.

```
INSERT INTO   TESTRETURN VALUES('1','ROW 1'), ('2','ROW 2');
SELECT * FROM TESTRETURN;



CREATE PROCEDURE TESTRETURN()
RETURNS TABLE()
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS

DECLARE

res Resultset;

BEGIN

res:= (SELECT * FROM TESTRETURN);

RETURN TABLE(res);

END;

CALL TESTRETURN();  SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
```